# Connecting a SQL server from a postgresql instance

Tags: postgresql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have an SQL server running with lot of existing Data and I need to connect it via postgresql instance which is on my system. I used the below link. But its not actually what I want.

http://blog.slalom.com/2011/03/14/connecting-to-a-postgresql-instance-using-sql-server-integration-services/

Can anyone suggest a clear way to attain this.?

Comment: What is your task? Do you want to migrate your data? From time to time copy data? Make queries on postgres using SQL Server as Data Source?

Comment: Make queries on postgres using SQL Server as Data Source

Comment: I think you're after [foreign data wrappers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createforeigndatawrapper.html), but as the docs say: _"At the moment, the foreign-data wrapper functionality is rudimentary."_

Comment: This link is probably more useful: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers

Comment: Hi, Can anyone Please give any clear step to connect.? I dont find any of them in the links provided.

Answer (score 4):

`SQL/MED` (implemented in PostgreSQL core as "foreign data wrappers") is supposed to solve this problem, but the current implementation in PostgreSQL is rather limited. See http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers . The ODBC FDW may be sufficient for your needs, give it a go and see.

Alternately, you can use `DBI-Link`, which uses Perl DBI drivers (including but not limited to the Perl DBI ODBC bridge) to talk to other databases. [You'll find dbi-link on PgFoundry](http://dbi-link.projects.pgfoundry.org/).

Comment: Can you please give the steps to use these FDWs on windows from PGAdmin?

Comment: @user1776417 I haven't used them myself, so I'd need to do the same reading and research you'd have to in order to write that up. At the moment I'm afraid time constraints prevent me from doing that. DBI-Link might be easier; it's more mature and well supported.